# ?? in OpenMP backtrace

Tags: c, debugging, pthreads

i have segfault coming from openmp (pthreads) region and I get very unhelpful:

```
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.11.1/string/wordcopy.c:85
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.11.1/string/./memmove.c:73
??:0
??:0
??:0
/usr/src/packages/BUILD/glibc-2.11.1/nptl/pthread_create.c:301
```

Any way to get the actual  backtrace within pthread context?

Answer (score 2):

Not mentioned by OP, but assuming it is using gcc/g++ to build code.

If the code is compiled with -g , 
then try using this command at gdb prompt when you debug the core:

```
thread apply all bt full
```

It would show all stack trace for each user created threads in the code.

Comment: "If the code is compiled with -g" -- this will also work just fine if the code is *not* compiled with `-g`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian - Yes thats true. I mentioned "-g" just to point the OP if he hadn't already since this option would only help his debug.